# How to upload a file to foreign (someone else) Google Cloud Storage using API?

Tags: api, gcloud, service-accounts

I have a simple and free Google user account like this: my.name@gmail.com.
Im working with SomeCompany with a billable Google account. This company exposed a bucket to which im supposed to upload someFile.txt. The bucket url looks like this: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/SomeCompany-multi-44444
or, alternatively gsutil:
gs://SomeCompany-multi-44444

I can access and use this bucket (after auth prompt) from my browser.

Question: Can i access this bucket using API (preferably using Python oauth2client or gcloud) without creating (billable) Service account of my own? How? I fail to understand how to create an API authentication to this bucket without creating a service account which requires credit card. Is there something that SomeCompany have to do in order for me to succeed?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible and reasonable.

Service accounts and user accounts are all Google identities (as are Groups).

The difference is that service accounts use two-legged auth and have a simpler flow. But, a user account is a valid identity and yours has been authorized to use the bucket.

The difference is that you need to use three-legged auth and exchange your credentials for an access token that you may use to authenticate to the service.

Here's a [link](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#user-accounts-3-legged-oauth-2-0-with-a-refresh-token) to the Python Cloud Client Library section on using 3-legged (User) auth.